# Scalebar Overlay and TikZ spy

Tags: tikz-pgf, spy

This question uses code snippets from [How to add a scalebar to an image](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67815/how-to-add-a-scalebar-to-an-image) and [Drawing on an image with TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9559/drawing-on-an-image-with-tikz).

I have an image with a scalebar (absolute positioning) overlay. Its length is determined by `ratio=absolute image length/scalebar length` which is used inside the image coordinate system `(0,0) to (1,1)`.

I woul like to add a scalebar (of choosable length) on a spy view. But to issue the same rectangle scalebar i would need to know the width of the spy view relativ to the original image. I then could calculate the scalebar as `ratio/(rel.view.width) * magnification`. Also im having trouble simply putting the zoom view into a scope with relative coordinates as the `zoom` node seems only usable when using further `\spy`commands.

What i would like to achieve:
[image: ScalebarSpy]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
% image source: http://www.mrulrichslandofbiology.com/images/cheek_cells_3.jpg
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,spy}

\newcommand{\scalebarandzoom}[4][white]{
 \begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily\small]

  % IMAGE
  \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) { #2 };

  % IMAGE SCOPE
  \begin{scope}[x={(image.south east)},y={(image.north west)},spy using outlines={rectangle,size=1in}]
       % Dirty hack so that spy sees the image content as it is otherwise
     % out of the scope:
       \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) { #2 };

     % GRID CODE
     %\draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
     %\foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (\x/10,0) {0.\x}; }
     %\foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,\y/10) {0.\y}; }

     % SCALEBAR
     \fill [#1,xshift=-2mm] (1-#4/#3,2mm) rectangle ++(#4/#3,1.5mm);
     % SPY
     \spy [red,magnification=3] on (0.6,0.4) in node (zoom) [right] at (1.1,0.5);
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}


\scalebarandzoom[orange]{\includegraphics[width=0.4\linewidth]{cheek.jpg}}{500}{50}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I used a different approach to get the desired result. Instead of `spy` library, I create two nodes: one for the image, other for the zoomed detail. I include the same image in both, but I clip the second one to the appropiate rectangle, and then use `\scalebox` to make it bigger.
You can also draw lines connecting both nodes (original image and zoomed details).

Since the factor applied to `\scalebox` is known, it is easy to determine also the dimensions of the "zoomed" scalebar.

I passed as parameters also the corners of the rectangle to be zoomed. Note however that I defined `x` and `y` with the same value, so that the helping grid has square cells. This means that, the image coordinate system goes from 0 to 1 for x axis, but not for y axis (unless the image is square itself).

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand\scalebarandzoom[8][white]{ 
% #1 = color of bar
% #2 = image size
% #3 = image
% #4 = lower left corner of viewport
% #5 = upper right corner of viewport
% #6 = magnification factor
% #7 = actual size of the image in some units
% #8 = actual size of the scalebar in the same units than #7
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=#2, y=#2, font=\footnotesize]
  \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] (image) at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=#2]{#3}};
  % \draw[help lines,xstep=.1,ystep=.1] (0,0) grid (1,1);
  % \foreach \x in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=north] at (0.\x,0) {.\x}; }
  % \foreach \y in {0,1,...,9} { \node [anchor=east] at (0,0.\y) {.\y}; }
  \coordinate (viewport lower left) at (#4);
  \coordinate (viewport upper right) at (#5);
  \draw[red] (viewport lower left) rectangle (viewport upper right);
  \node[right=of image, draw=red, inner sep=1pt] (zoom) {%
       \scalebox{#6}{\tikz{
          \clip (#4) rectangle (#5);
          \node[anchor=south west,inner sep=0] at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=#2]{#3}};
         }}%
       };
  % Help lines
  \draw[red, dashed] (viewport lower left|-viewport upper right) -- (zoom.north west);
  \draw[red, dashed] (viewport lower left) -- (zoom.south west);
  % Scalebars
  \fill [#1] (image.south east) ++(-2mm,2mm) ++(-#8/#7,    0mm) rectangle ++(#8/#7,   1.5mm);
  \fill [#1] (zoom.south east)  ++(-2mm,2mm) ++(-#8/#7*#6, 0mm) rectangle ++(#8/#7*#6,1.5mm);
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\scalebarandzoom[orange]{6cm}{cheek.png}{0.52, 0.23}{0.68,0.35}{3}{500}{50}
\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image: Result]

(image `cheek.png` can be found [here](http://classconnection.s3.amazonaws.com/832/flashcards/696866/jpg/cheek_cells_3.jpg))

Comment: I would add text under the zoomed figure. How can I do? I tried the command \draw (x,y) {Text} but without any result

Comment: @Mazzy Use `\node` instead of `\draw`, and you don't even need to use coordinates: `\node[below=3mm of zoom] {Text}`